# Choose between two tables before select

Tags: sql-server

I have a code similar to this:

```
IF @a = 'does not matter'
  SELECT /* 500+ lines long query */ FROM TABLE_A;
ELSE
  SELECT /* 500+ lines long query */ FROM TABLE_B;
```

The code do what it it supposed to do, but it is a pain to maintain it.  I hate this code, I hate that I did it.  Every change to the first query needs to be reproduced to the second query (the queries are identical), and this task is very prone to errors.

So, is there a way to create a kind of 'pointer' to a table in SQL Server?  Something like:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE_REF;

IF @a = 'does not matter'
  SET @table = TABLE_A;
ELSE
  SET @table = TABLE_B;

SELECT /* 500+ lines long query */ FROM @table;
```

I am not looking for a dynamic query solution.  I already know that I can build this query into a string and run it using `sp_executesql`.  I was wondering if there is another solution, since my code is not dynamic at all, it is static in fact.  I have only two possibilities and I want to choose between them.

Also, create a copy of TABLE_A or TABLE_B also are not good options, since they are very large tables.

Comment: Probably NOT possible without Dynamic Query. Other option is the `UNION ALL` but again change will be needed in both union parts.

Comment: well, you can't use an object (like a table) in / with a variable without dynamic sql. So that should sum up your question. What do you have against the dynamic sql in this case? seems to be a good idea over managing two sets of code.

Comment: The solution is the one that you've already rejected - dynamic SQL, building the query as a string and passing it to `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic Query may be the best solution for this.

Alternatively, you could create a SYNONYM for your table

```
IF @a = 'does not matter'
  CREATE SYNONYM TABLE_NEW FOR TABLE_A;
ELSE
  CREATE SYNONYM TABLE_NEW FOR TABLE_B;

SELECT /* 500+ lines long query */ FROM TABLE_NEW

DROP  SYNONYM TABLE_NEW
```

Comment: Great answer! Your _alternative_ solution fit my needs!

Comment: Note: This will not work if the code is called more than once at the same time. Good for situations that are not concurrent.

Comment: I like it as a suggestion but it does also require some additional permissions.  "a user must have CREATE SYNONYM permission and either own the schema or have ALTER SCHEMA permission."

Comment: @ShannonSeverance I guessed about the concurrency thing, but this is not a problem for me in this particular case. But I wonder if I am ok if the CREATE and DROP statements are inside a transaction. What do you think?

Comment: @DiegoQueiroz, SQL Server allows DDL, including `create synonym` to be inside a multi-statement transaction. The second `create synonym` will then block until the first transaction ends. (Results probably depend on isolation level.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(4000);

DECLARE @A AS VARCHAR(40);

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME AS VARCHAR(40);

BEGIN

```
IF @A='BLABLA'
    @TABLE_NAME='MARIA'
ELSE
    @TABLE_NAME='JOSE'
EXEC sp_executesql CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @TABLE_NAME, ' WHERE BLA BLA BLA');
```

END

Comment: I was already aware of this possibility, but it has several drawbacks that I do not want to deal with. Particularly, I was not really sincere and I do not run only one SELECT statement, there are several statements and I also iterate over a cursor as part of the process. So it is a full TSQL program, not just a single statement as I presented. My goal was to make the code more readable and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details about the actual query or tables it's hard to come up with a creative solution that we know will work.

How about something like this

```
SELECT /* 500+ lines long query */ FROM 
(SELECT * , A as tableName from TABLE_A
  UNION ALL
 SELECT * , B from TABLE_B) as x
 Where x.tableName = @a
```

This assumes your two tables have the same number, order, types, etc of columns or you'd have to update it to select matching sets of columns. I also make no guarantee's about the performance when doing a UNION of two large tables.

Comment: You solution works, but I feel that any creative solution would not be an option in this case. You guessed right, both tables have the same structure and fields, but they are also very large. All this procedure exists exactly because a simple aggregation does not perform fast as we need, so the solution was to prepare the data into a staging table. It is doing what it is supposed to do and fast as we want, but the goal was only to make the code more readable.